# D3 force simulation with svelte

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svelte, force-layout

I'm building a d3 force simulation that's working fine in plain d3 (I was testing it in Observable [here](https://observablehq.com/@sechodosh/60daysofmylife)), but I'm struggling to translate it to svelte, I think in part because I'm fetching data from a URL and the promise is tripping me up.

The data comes through fine and the svg populates with circles, but the circles are just stacked on top of each other in 3 groups. I'm clearly not actually running the simulation, but am confused what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
<script>
    import * as d3 from 'd3';
    import rough from 'roughjs';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    //import {forceSimulation} from 'd3Force';

    let width = 800;
    let height = 800;

    const m = 3;

    const colors = {
        words: '#fcd6d9',
        acts: '#fcb6be',
        gifts: '#f995a4',
        time: '#f3728d',
        touch: '#ec4977'
    }

    let points;
    let simulation;

    const rawData = d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sarachodosh/60days/main/60days_data.csv')
        .then(data => {
            
            points = data.map(d => {
                let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m) //the cluster id
                let focusX = 110 * Math.cos(i / m * Math.PI * 2)
                let focusY = 110 * Math.sin(i / m * Math.PI * 2)

                let dataPoint = {
                    day: d.day,
                    cluster: +d.cluster,
                    person: d.person,
                    act_type: d.act_type,
                    r: d.person === 'both' ? 10 : 15,
                    x: focusX,
                    y: focusY,
                    focusX: focusX,
                    focusY: focusY
                } 
                return dataPoint

            })
        
            console.log(points)
            
            simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
                .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width/2, height/2))
                .nodes(points)
                .on("tick", () => {
                    points = points
                    
                })      
            
            simulation.tick()
            
        })

</script>

<main>

<svg viewBox='0 0 {width} {height}'>
    <g>
        {#if points}
        {#each points as d}
            <circle r='{d.r}' cx='{d.x}' cy='{d.y}' fill='{colors[d.act_type]}'></circle>
        {/each}
        {/if}
    </g>
</svg>

</main>
```

Comment: Just responding to my own question since it's now coming up in my own Google search results to say that I found a workaround! Run the simulation somewhere else (I did it in Observable, since it was already there) and then just save the x,y coordinates that the simulation creates. Then plot your dots like a scatterplot.